# Custom cakeError

Tags: cakephp, custom-error-pages

This is what I have:

**comments_controller.php**

```
if (empty($result)) { //$result is empty if comment does not exist
    $this->cakeError('error404', array('message'=>'Comment not found'));
} elseif ($result['spam'] == 1) {
    $this->cakeError('spam', array('message'=>'SPAM!!!'));
}
```

**app_error.php**

```
function error404($params) {
    $this->controller->set('title', 'Page not found');
    $this->controller->set('message', $params['message']);
    $this->_outputMessage('error404');
}

function spam($params) {
    $this->controller->set('title', 'Spam');
    $this->controller->set('message', $params['message']);
    $this->_outputMessage('spam');
}
```

And I created **error404.ctp** and **spam.ctp** inside *app/views/errors*

The problem is that when the comment is a spam ($result['spam'] == 1), cakePHP loads the error404 layout. But strangely, it shows the message for a spam comment ("SPAM!!!").

When it is a comment that does not exist, the correct error404 layout is loaded.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Problem fixed. The code was right, but the server had to be restarted. It shouldn't be necessary, but this was what fixed the problem. Maybe cake was not following the correct path of the new *app_error.php* file.

Comment: What's the value of debug in app/config/core.php?

Comment: Configure::write('debug', 0);
It is fixed now.

Comment: Cake Error sounds kinda funny.

Answer (score 0):

I very quickly tried your setup (CakePHP 1.3) and it worked fine.

My best guess is that you have a typo in either one of the filenames or class names and it is using error404 because it can't find something.

After checking this I would turn on the debugger, or you can start throwing in

```
die('got here: ' . __METHOD__ . __LINE__ );
```

statements until you work out the execution order.

Comment: After doing what you mentioned, I noticed that cake was not catching the things as it should. I tried restarting apache and for some reason it fixed the problem. Weird.

Comment: Glad it is fixed. By the way, there's an interesting note about errors and 404s here:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1581/Miscellaneous